# Is there a template or a package giving this formatting?

Tags: formatting, packages, templates

I have found two (unrelated) documents that have the same style (the same formatting), so I believe the authors used the same template or package to create their files. I don't know how or where to look for such templates.
Does anyone recognize what might have been used to create the following chapter page and text, as shown below?

[image: chapter]

[image: text]